# Encrypting swap on 16.04 LTS with ecryptfs-setup-swap

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, encryption, swap

I just encrypted my home folder with no issues whatsoever using

```
ecryptfs-migrate-home
```

But then, when it comes to encrypting swap, the story is different.

```
sudo ecryptfs-setup-swap
[sudo] password for ratatouyee: 

WARNING:
An encrypted swap is required to help ensure that encrypted files are not leaked to disk in an unencrypted format.

HOWEVER, THE SWAP ENCRYPTION CONFIGURATION PRODUCED BY THIS PROGRAM WILL BREAK HIBERNATE/RESUME ON THIS SYSTEM!

NOTE: Your suspend/resume capabilities will not be affected.

Do you want to proceed with encrypting your swap? [y/N]: y

INFO: Setting up swap: [/dev/sda6]
WARNING: Commented out your unencrypted swap from /etc/fstab
/dev/sda6 is already marked as no-auto
swapon: stat of /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 failed: No such file or directory
```

Swap become unavailable, so i have to revert my fstab and crypttab files and then swapon -a, but the swap isn't encrypted, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug in ecryptfs-utils.

#### Step 1

Open `/etc/crypttab` and replace:

```
cryptswap1 UID=XXXXXXXX /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

with:

```
cryptswap1 /swapfile /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

#### Step 2

Open `/etc/fstab` and ensure that it ends with the following:

```
#/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

#### Step 3

Restart computer. After restart, verify that the swap file is encrypted:

```
sudo cryptsetup status cryptswap1
```

It should show:

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is active and is in use.
```

References:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/1670336
- http://www.askmeaboutlinux.com/?p=1949

Comment: But I don't have a swap file, I use a swap partition.

Comment: If `Step 3` showed that cryptswap1 is not found, issue the following command: `sudo cryptdisks_start cryptswap1`